# Replacing comma with concatenating operator in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a base table where a field contains value of field names separated with comma.

I am trying to get the field value and query it another table to get the concatenated value.

E.g Base table A has a field Target_field which contains value such as : Addr_1,Addr2,Zip. I am trying to replace the , with + ' ' + so that when i use that field to query from another table, i get the concatenated value.

I could have used concat() function, but i want a space after a each field value.

Could you please help.

Comment: Can you post queries you tried with current values and desired output?

Comment: is it what you looking for `concat (field1+' ' +field2+' ' + field3)` ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you may looking for REPLACE function

```
REPLACE('Addr_1,Addr2,Zip', ',' ,'+'' ''+')
```